# Applied vs academic future goals

Tags: statement-of-purpose, academic-life

The universities and programmes I am going to apply emphasizes their research, hands-on experience, startup environment, etc as well as strong academia.

Is it fine to state in the Statement of Purpose that after graduating I would like to apply the knowledge to non-academical area?

Comment: As opposed to lying?

Comment: Is thin an undergrad or grad-level application?

Answer (score 1):

If that's your plan, I don't see why you can't say that. I think that you institutions know that not everyone who does a thesis has to work in Academia!

If you are worried that mentioning that would hurt your chances of being accepted/getting funded, then I can see that some schools/faculty might shy away from your application (although in theory, they shouldn't! [depending on the institution]).

Remember, people change their opinions with time! Maybe after a while you want to work in Academia! Maybe someone who stated that they wanna work in academia in their SOP, decides to not do that few years in their program. This is why I'm saying it shouldn't matter that much ch.

Once you get your degree, you can anything you want!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the alternative would be to either write nothing about your future plans or to lie about them, it seems clear that sticking to the truth is the best option. I myself find it convincing and a good motivation if somebody says the she wants higher education to use it for some practical purposes afterwards.